# How to open directory from terminal in vs code? but inside the same window

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I have vs code open and I'm using bash terminal within it, when I'm inside the directory I want to open I type code . and that opens everything I want but it opens a new vs code window. Is there a way it can open inside of the current vs code window I am in?

Answer (score 3):

Try `code . -r` to force opening in the same window.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_core-cli-options for more options in the command line.

For a more "permanent" solution there is this setting:

> Window: Open Files In New Window
>
> Controls whether files should open in a new window. Note that there
>   can still be cases where this setting is ignored (e.g. when using the
>   `--new-window` or `--reuse-window` command line option).

Set it to `off` and then ``code .` is enough.